# Bootstrap theme buttons

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I downloaded a Bootstrap theme - and am trying to change the colours of the buttons (in the top right of this link: http://twcc.se/onepageproduct/) - I can't seem to be able to replace the main blue colour (active button) to e.g. a dark red....

Really unsure why this is not working - I have tried changing the css elements connected to the buttons.

Comment: Probably because it uses background-image for gradient coloring, which overlays any background color. Use Chrome's built in tool or for example Firebug to play around with the CSS.

Answer (score 1):

just go to their general.css  line 114

```
 .navbar .nav .active a {
-moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
-moz-border-left-colors: none;
-moz-border-right-colors: none;
-moz-border-top-colors: none;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #92DBFF 0%, #4FB6E9 5%, #39A0D3 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
border-color: #3CA3D7 #3799CA #338BB8;
border-image: none;
border-radius: 16px 16px 16px 16px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
color: #FFFFFF;
text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #3799CA;
```

}

Change the color of background to what ever you need.

Note: They are using gradient buttons 
Use this [Link1](http://gradients.glrzad.com/) and [Link2](http://cssgradientbutton.com/) for further details

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer Vivek! 

I will keep playing with this in general.css - the code is a bit different in the css (they use RGB) ... but I will keep trying!  And thanks for the links :)  Very useful!

Comment: They just turn their hex values to rgb values if you know your hex values just google them and get their rgb values :)